# Framework7 .addView is not a function

Tags: javascript, cordova, user-interface, frameworks

I'm trying to create a Cordova app using Framework7 as my UI. I'm trying to use inline pages as the layout architecture but in setting up my project I'm receiving the following error in the console:

Uncaught TypeError: myApp.addView is not a function

This is in reaction to the config:

```
    // Initialize your app
    var myApp = new Framework7({
        animateNavBackIcon:true
    });

    // Export selectors engine
    var $$ = Dom7;

    // Add main View
    var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main', {
      // Enable dynamic Navbar
      dynamicNavbar: true,
      // Enable Dom Cache so we can use all inline pages
      domCache: true
    });
```

Does anyone know what is causing this and how I can correct it? Also, does anyone have a working template/code sample for a Framework7 inline pages app that I could use as mine is clearly not working.

Cheers

Comment: I'm having the same problem on an F7 app that used to work before the latest update.

Answer (score 1):

just use version 1.6.5
link here!
https://github.com/framework7io/framework7/releases/tag/v1.6.5

i think version over the 2 that is Weird and not updated guide

Answer (score 1):

Second answer, more knowledge.  It seems the F7 docs were out of date, but have now been updated.  In order to get past the error, change the following:

OLD:  `app.addView(el,{...})`  NEW: `app.views.add(el,{...})`

A few other things that have changed:

- OLD: `app.hideIndicator()` and `app.showIndicator()` NEW:  `app.preloader.show()` and `app.preloader.hide()`
- OLD: `app.searchBar(el, {...})` NEW: `app.searchbar.create(el,{...})`
- OLD: `app.pullToRefreshDone()` NEW: `app.ptr.done()`

And surely more.  Check your console for errors and update using the docs for reference: http://framework7.io/docs/

Comment: Looks like it has now changed to app.views.create

Answer (score 0):

Try put CSS class view-main on your div like this:

```
<!-- Views -->
<div class="views">
  <!-- Your main view, should have "view-main" class -->
  <div class="view view-main">
```

Comment: I already have that. That's why this is so damn confusing! :(

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem on an F7 app that used to work before the latest update.  Turns out I inadvertently installed a beta version that was incomplete (or at least materially different)  I installed 1.6.5 and the issue went away.

Comment: I'm using Intel XDK for my app dev, can you tell me how to install it other than just copying the dist folder into the www, and then linking to it from indext.html? Or is that fine?

Thanks so much for your tip! Please advise where I can download/install 1.6.5 from. I'm an amateur dev, so not too clued up :)

Comment: Hard to say.  Install procedures differ across environments and I've never used Intel XDK.   On most projects, I'll just copy the specific F7 files that I need from the /dist folder into the place where other js & css are in my project (e.g.,  /static/scripts and /static/styles folders)  Usually, you want to grab the .min versions instead of the expanded files.